# How to build ELF file for each applet in busybox?

Tags: linux, build, cross-platform, mips, busybox

Assume, my busybox has two applets: `cat`, `touch` and it runs on `mips` arch.

Now I want two ELF file (cat & touch) in order to run on `mips`, no shared lib, static.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this FAQ](https://www.busybox.net/FAQ.html#getting_started) (see `Installing Busybox`), you can create symbolic links to one Busybox binary each with a name of the utility you need. Then Busybox will detect as which utility it was invoked and behave accordingly.